# What is the Range for Magic Tower?

Tags: defender-2

One of the new abilities in Defender II is the "Magic Tower".  Since I never upgraded City Wall in the original, it would be a sizable investment for me just to find out if it's any good.

So at what range does it begin attacking monsters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts attacking to a range from the wall up to 3/4 of the screen. Heard that it slowly regenerates mana as well.

Comment: I don't see anything in-game to support the second statement, but your first answer appears to be accurate.